# Merging two SQLite tables from the same database with python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a new table that combines columns from two different tables using an id column that is common to both as a keyword. Let's imagine then that I have a database named db.db that includes two tables named table1 and table2.

table1 looks like this:

```
id | item | price
-------------
 1 | book | 20  
 2 | copy | 30   
 3 | pen  | 10
```

and table2 like this:

```
id | shop | color
-------------
 1 |  11  | blue  
 2 |  34  | red   
 3 |  25  | red
```

What should I write in sqlite3 to have something like this??

```
id | item | price | shop | color
-------------------------------
 1 | book | 20    |  11  | blue 
 2 | copy | 30    |  34  | red   
 3 | pen  | 10    |  25  | red
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new SQLite table combining column from other tables with sqlite3 and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767758/create-new-sqlite-table-combining-column-from-other-tables-with-sqlite3-and-pyth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: try to change the LEFT JOIN for INNER JOIN to see if it works.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')   
c = conn.cursor()

def merged():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id')
    for line in c.fetchall():
        print(line)
merged()
```

Comment: I have tried your approach that but when I query, table 2 still has the same name of columns. I would like to have a table3 that has the 4 columns

Comment: i editted. try to change the left join for inner join

Comment: I tried again with INNER JOINT but still, I have the number of columns in table2 than at the beginning. But ive tried the following and works, maybe I didnt explain well what i wanted:
 'CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id'

Comment: great, i am glad that you got it right. i will put that in the final answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, sqlite3
d1 = list(sqlite3.connect('db.db').cursor().execute("SELECT id, item, price FROM table1"))
d2 = list(sqlite3.connect('db.db').cursor().execute("SELECT id, item, price FROM table2"))
full_data = sorted(d1+d2, key=lambda x:x[0])
grouped = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(full_data, key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_grouped = [[a, *[i for c in b for i in c[1:]]] for a, b in grouped]
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE file3 (id real, item text, price real, shop real, color text)')
conn.executemany('INSERT INTO file3 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', final_grouped)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```